# Xcode stuck on 'installing components'

Tags: macos, xcode

I have installed Xcode 7.3.1 on OS X El Capitan and when I want to open it, it says components need to be installed. When clicking on install, the progress goes until over half the bar and then it stops. I don't know if I should wait or not?

Comment: I uninstalled 8.2 and installed 9.1 ......I am also facing same issue on xcode 9 ....macOS High Sierra.....i almost tried twice and waited half day

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because I was already busy installing an update on my iPhone while trying to update XCode - check that you are not already keeping the PackageKit system (system_installd) in an idle state (busy installing) which can cause these freezes / crashes.